# Property [amount] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel

I've checked the related questions, but didn't manage to get a breakthrough.

Maybe I'm to tired to detect. But I get an Exeption (Property [amount] does not exist on this collection instance). Why? How to revrite the condition?

```
  $pruef=DB::table('bill AS re')
  ->leftjoin('approvals as fg', 'fg.id', 're.id')
  ->where('re.int_key', '=', $rinkey)
  ->select(DB::raw("re.amount, fg.approval1"))
  ->get();
  if($pruef->amount<3000)
```

Dump looks like:

```
Collection {#307 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => {#304 ▼
      +"amount": "140"
      +"approval1": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$pruef` is a `Collection`; you can't access `amount` (a property of a single instance) without looping, or returning only a single result:

```
$pruef=DB::table('bill AS re')
  ->leftjoin('approvals as fg', 'fg.id', 're.id')
  ->where('re.int_key', '=', $rinkey)
  ->select(DB::raw("re.amount, fg.approval1"))
  ->get();

  foreach($pruef AS $record){
     if($record->amount < 3000){ 
       ...
     }
  }
```

Or

```
$pruef=DB::table('bill AS re')
  ->leftjoin('approvals as fg', 'fg.id', 're.id')
  ->where('re.int_key', '=', $rinkey)
  ->select(DB::raw("re.amount, fg.approval1"))
  ->first();

  if($pruef->amount < 3000){ 
    ...
  }
```

Comment: @vadim Kotov just as it's stated above make use of `->first()` rather than `->get()` to access it as a single object instead of a collection (Array).